# How to Add text with superscript to a Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML button like

```
<input type="button" id="button" onclick="showSuper()" value="Click Me!" />
```

Inside JavaScript, I have

```
var showSuper = function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    var spanSuper = "<sup>3</sup>";
    btn.value="You Clicked Me " +  spanSuper;
    //btn.value = "You Clicked Me " + <sup>a</sup>;
}
```

With the above function the button value is getting replaced with `You Clicked Me <sup>3</sup>`

I also tried with the comment statement that also didn't succeed. How can add a superscripted text to the button?

Comment: not sure exactly what you are asking here.  From your question it seems the code is working fine.  Your original button text is preserved and the number 3 is being added as a supertext, what result were you hoping for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need script to do this. Use this instead

```
<button name="button" id="button" onclick="showSuper()">Click Me!</button>
```

Script

```
var showSuper = function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    var spanSuper = "<sup>3</sup>";
    btn.innerHTML= "You Clicked Me " +  spanSuper;
}
```

Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/ELbxG/). **[Updated Demo with your solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/ELbxG/1/)**

Comment: Startx, Thanks for the reply.  But I need to add it dynamically. Only on click.

Comment: @Sajja, My name is Starx, not Startx :P. Wait for the update for your answer

Comment: @Starx, sorry for the misspell. Changing input to button and .value to .innerHTML solved my problem. Is there any way to format the value of input type="button".

Comment: @Sajja, you dont need to be sorry for a silly thing. Coming to the point, `value` is a attribute of `input` element so there is no way you can add `inner html tags` inside a attribute's value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of the button after click. As per Starx suggested add something like this.

HTML

```
<button onclick="showSuper(this);">Click Me</button>
```

JS

```
function showSuper(btn){

    btn.innerHTML="You Clicked Me" + "<sup>3</sup>";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Unicode text like this: `<input type="button" value="☺" />` or you can do this`<sup>1</sup>` AND then copy the one or this ¹ aka`value="¹"

Things You Can do to get them:

SEARCH Alt(unicode) superscript (Letter or number)
and you should find somthing like this
fn alt(laptop)or alt (numlock on) 1223 and release all at the same time